# html2canvas v1.0.0 rc 5 does not work on ios

Tags: javascript, html, html2canvas

I'm using niklavsh version of html2canvas. Because it supports the transform css property so i can translate my image. On my android and windows, it works perfectly but when i tested it on my ios it didn't capture/load the image. Then i tried lowering its version from rc 5 to rc 1 it worked but the image transform doesn't work so it overlapped on my container. Please help!

This is my javascript code:

[image]